# using a value from select HTML PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to get a value from a select but i don't get how to do it, here is my code:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="List">
        <?php while($Adresses = mysqli_fetch_array($adress)) { ?> 
            <option value="<?php echo  $Addresses[0];?>"><?php echo  $Addresses[0]; ?> </option><?php } ?>
    </select>

<input type="submit" name="Edit" value="Edit"> 
</form>
```

I need the value of the selected address here:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['Edit'])):
       $_SESSION['adress']= $_POST['List'];?>
      <p><b>Change your adress:</b> <input type="text" name="new_adress" value= "<?php echo $_SESSION['adress']; ?> " /></p>
      <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"> 
      <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
  <?php endif; ?>
```

and this is the error message:

```
Undefined index: List
```

I have tried

```
   <?php $_SESSION['adress']= $_GET['List'];
```

but it did not work either...
thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: Your form is a post method, use the same for your `['List']`

Comment: Make sure you're loading `session_start();` also. It's required when using sessions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added it to the list and i have 'session_start();' at the beginnig of my code, still not working...

Comment: There is no endif in PHP code.

Comment: @Edrich yes, there is

Comment: add form action='' into form

Comment: @srinath it was the action thing and other mistakes, I could solve it at the end. Thank you all for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a serverside language.

HTML, CSS, and JavaScript are clientside languages.

PHP is for sending out HTML, CSS, and JavaScript data. To send from HTML to PHP you need to submit your form.

In your html:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action='test.php' method='post'>
      <?php
        echo "
          <input name='name' value='" . $_SESSION['name'] . "'>
          <input name='address' value='" . $_SESSION['name'] . "'>
        ";
      ?>
      <input type='submit' value='Update Information'>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

In your 'test.php':

```
<?php
  $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
  $_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
?>
```

This will save it into your session. To actually save it you need to look into SQL or XML data parsing.

The only way to process data from HTML => PHP is with form submitting. PHP is processed by the server, not your internet browser.

Comment: Since i have been learning PHP from yesterday, this is a really good explanation about how to manipulate data, i still don't get the data that i need, but i'll keep on trying

Comment: at the end, I could solve it, your post was really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `POST` for getting the data.

```
<?php $_SESSION['adress']= $_POST['List'];
```